# Why is the Base class data initialized before Derived class data

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

Consider this code:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(): m_i{10} {}
private:
  int m_i;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  Derived(): m_f{100.0} {}
private:
  float m_f;
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
}
```

When `Derived d;` is instantiated C++ first calls `Base()` constructor and initializes `Base`'s data - `m_i` - and only then calls `Derived()` constructor and initializes `Derived`'s data - `m_f`.

But what is the reason for it?

Why C++ doesn't do it the other way?

Because, from what I can tell, it isn't faster or something.

Comment: If you're building a house do you start with the roof or the foundation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The main reason for it is - `Derived` class should have access to `Base` class fields.

Let me explain with an example:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(): m_i(10) {}
protected:
  int m_i;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  Derived(): m_f(100.0) {
    m_i = 1;
  }
  void print() {
    std::cout << "Derived m_f=" << m_f << ", m_i=" << m_i << '\n';
  }
private:
  float m_f;
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.print(); // prints: "Derived m_f=100, m_i=1"
}
```

If the initialization happened the other way around `Derived` could access uninitialized data in `Base`, which is bad.

Also `Derived()` constructor wouldn't have the ability to change the `Base` field values correctly and you would get "`Derived m_f=100, m_i=10`" printed, because `m_i=1;` in `Derived()` would happen first and `m_i{10}` would happen next and it simply looks confusing.

2) I can think about the other reason as well:

Imagine the following - `Base()` constructor throws the exception and have to clean up after himself.

If we already initialized `Derived` it would mean that we now have to clean up after `Derived` too, which is overhead.